# Javascript Click on Element by Class

Tags: javascript, click

So I am writing a script that can be run on a page but I want to click on this element, unfortunately, it does not have an `id` to get and I am trying to use the `.click()` function on it, but it doesn't work, here's what I have, anyone know how to fix it? This is the only element in the class also

```
var classes = document.getElementsByClassName('rateRecipe btns-one-small');
var Rate = classes[0];
Rate.click();
```

Comment: "*This is the only element in the class*" - okay, the only element with *which* class, you've listed *two* in the selector?

Comment: in the rateRecipe class and btns-one-small

Comment: When you have a question about DOM selection, you need to post the DOM you're selecting so that we can see what's wrong. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: in your case - document.getElementsByClassName('rateRecipe btns-one-small')[0].click();  - should work . I usually do this it works.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
document.querySelector('.rateRecipe.btns-one-small').click();
```

The above code assumes that the given element has *both* of those classes; otherwise, if the space is meant to imply an ancestor-descendant relationship:

```
document.querySelector('.rateRecipe .btns-one-small').click();
```

The method `getElementsByClassName()` takes a single class-name (rather than `document.querySelector()`/`document.querySelectorAll()`, which take a CSS selector), and you passed two (presumably class-names) to the method.

References:

- [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByClassName).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).

Comment: Just FYI, `getElementsByClassName` accepts multiple classes, so @user3010773's original code will work just fine if he was trying to select a single element that has both classes. http://jsfiddle.net/u94wtpcn/

Answer (score 21):

If you want to click on **all** elements selected by some class, you can use this example (used on [last.fm](http://last.fm) on the Loved tracks page to Unlove all).

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.love-button.love-button--loved'); 

for (i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
  divs[i].click();
};
```

With ES6 and Babel (cannot be run in the browser console directly)

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.love-button.love-button--loved')]
   .forEach(div => { div.click(); })
```

Comment: And loop is probably preferable to to `[...document.querySelectorAll('.love-button.love-button--loved')].forEach(div => { div.click(); })`, what do you think?

Comment: @AS I think the proposed code is less performant but of course more beautiful with ES6. Will add it to the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

for exactly what you want (if you know the index of button):

```
var rate = document.getElementsByClassName('rateRecipe btns-one-small')[0];
rate.click();
```

**or for direct action**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('rateRecipe btns-one-small')[0].click();
```

with jQuery

```
$('.rateRecipe .btns-one-small').click(function(){
    var vIndex = $('.rateRecipe .btns-one-small').index(this);
    //vIndex is the index of buttons out of multiple
    
    //do whatever 
    //alert($(this).val());//for value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

class of my button is "input-addon btn btn-default fileinput-exists"

below code helped me

```
document.querySelector('.input-addon.btn.btn-default.fileinput-exists').click();
```

but I want to click second button, I have two buttons in my screen so I used querySelectorAll

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.input-addon.btn.btn-default.fileinput-exists');
                elem[1].click();
```

here elem[1] is the second button object that I want to click.