# JavaScript script click button

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension and i need JavaScript to click on this button, but it is not working.

**This is the button that needs to be clicked with JavaScript.**

`<a class="button checkout" data-no-turbolink="true" href="...">checkout</a>`

**This is what I tried but it is not working**

`document.getElementsByClassName("button checkout").click();`

Comment: I believe this question got answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587762/javascript-click-on-element-by-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the index

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button checkout")[0].click()
```

```js
function clickme(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("button checkout")[0].click()
}

function clicked(){
  alert('It works!!!!!!')
}
```

```html
<a class="button checkout" data-no-turbolink="true" href="www.google.com" onclick="clicked()">checkout</a>
<hr/>
<button onclick="clickme()">Click div</button>
```

Comment: That only works with one className, not with two as the TS has.

Comment: https://codepen.io/GuiZanetti/pen/PoWGaZa 

so what is this?

Answer (score 0):

When you getting an element by class name it comes in form of an array with all of the elements having this class name, so you're trying to use .click() method on the array rather than an element. Consider switching from a class name to an id which would be unique just for that element.

```
<a id="button-checkout" data-no-turbolink="true" href="...">checkout</a>

document.getElementsById("button-checkout").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give the button a unique `id`and instead of `click()` use an event listener.

HTML

`<a class="button checkout" id="click_me" data-no-turbolink="true" href="...">checkout</a>`

JS

```
document.getElementById('click_me').addEventListener('click', () => {
  //Your code here
})
```

Comment: If you use an even listener, the user still has to click manually. The TS wants to simulate the click with Javascript.