# add style with javascript to each element

Tags: javascript, html

I want add class to my div
but I have so many div and any time clicked button just add or remove on one div in html
how can I do?
is there any way to use value or id?
such as that link in command

if you lock i have to button to show&hide dive but no matter which one is clicked it's just add class to first one

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Ahok-re/pen/wvpZMOV

Comment: Please edit the question to include the [mcve].

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean for toggle class `slow` you can use `e.target` with `next()` for toggle element like:

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).next().toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
body {padding:30px;}

#target {
  background:#0099cc;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  height:160px;
  padding:5px;
  display:none;
}

.Hide
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button class="toggle">Show &amp; Hide</button>
<div>
  <p>test1</p>
</div>
  
</div>
<div>
  <button class="toggle">Show &amp; Hide</button>
<div>
  <p>test2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `data-target` like:

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    $('#'+ e.target.dataset.target).toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
body {padding:30px;}

.target {
  background:#0099cc;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  height:160px;
  padding:5px;
  display:none;
}

.Hide
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button class="toggle" data-target="target-1">Show &amp; Hide</button>
<div id="target-1" class="target">
  <p>test1</p>
</div>
  
</div>
<div>
  <button class="toggle" data-target="target-2">Show &amp; Hide</button>
<div id="target-2" class="target">
  <p>test2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Another rule you must learn, **id must be unique**.

Reference:

- [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
- [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)
- [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Comment: tnx this is any thing i search it

Answer (score 0):

You can have many divs with the same class but if your looking to do something more specific to a particular div you have to use id or a seperate class. Read more about CSS selectors

```
<div class="blue" id="standout">Hello world</div>
<div class="blue">Hello world</div>
<div class="blue">Hello world</div>
<div class="blue">Hello world</div>

.blue{
text-align: center;
}

 #standout{
text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add a class (or id) to the button like this:

```
<button class="foo-class" id="foo-id">Click me</button>
```

And then you can access the click on the button with the following javascript:

```
// class
document.querySelector('.foo-class').click(
  // do something
);

// id 
document.getElementById("foo-id").click(
   // do something
);
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for reference the id and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587762/javascript-click-on-element-by-class) the reference for class.